# How to get the content of all spans that have the email attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to find all spans in a document that have the "email" attribute and then for each email address i'll check with my server if the email is approved and inject to the span
content an img with a "yes" or a "no". I don't need the implementation of the PHP side, only JavaScript.

So say "newsletter@zend.com" is approved in my db and the HTML code is:

```
<span dir="ltr"><span class="yP" email="newsletter@zend.com">Zend Technologies</span></span>
```

Then the JavaScript will change the HTML to:

```
<span dir="ltr"><span class="yP" email="newsletter@zend.com"><img src="yes.gif" />Zend Technologies</span></span>
```

I need someone to guide me to the right direction on how to approach this.

Note: i don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library, and you don't want to limit yourself to browsers that support `querySelectorAll`, you're probably best off with a simple recursive-descent function or `getElementsByTagName`. Here's an RD example:

The function (off-the-cuff, untested):

```
function findEmailSpans(container, callback) {
    var node, emailAttr;
    for (node = container.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.tagName === "SPAN") { // 1 = Element
                emailAttr = node.getAttribute("email");
                if (emailAttr) {
                    callback(node, emailAttr);
                }
            }
        }
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case 1:  // Element
            case 9:  // Document
            case 11: // DocumentFragment
                findEmailSpans(node, callback);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
findEmailSpans(document.documentElement, function(span, emailAttr) {
    // Do something with `span` and `emailAttr`
});
```

Alternately, if you want to rely on [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) (which is *quite* widely supported) and don't mind building such a large `NodeList` in memory, that would be simpler and *might* be faster: It would let you get one flat `NodeList` of all `span` elements, so then you'd just have a simple loop rather than a recursive-descent function (not that the RD function is either difficult or slow, but still). Something like this:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span"),
    index, node, emailAttr;
for (index = 0; index < spans.length; ++index) {
    node = spans.item(index);
    emailAttr = node.getAttribute("email");
    if (emailAttr) {
        // Do something with `node` and `emailAttr`
    }
}
```

You'll want to compare and decide which method suits you best, each probably has pros and cons.

References:

- [DOM3 Core Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)

---

**However**, for this sort of thing I really would recommend getting and using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). With any good library, it can look something like this (jQuery):

```
$("span[email]").each(function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the span that has an email attribute
});
```

...or this (Prototype):

```
$$("span[email]").each(function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the span that has an email attribute
});
```

...and the others won't be massively more complex. Using a library to factor our common ops like searching for things in the DOM lets you concentrate on the actual problem you're trying to solve. Both jQuery and (recent versions of) Prototype will defer to `querySelectorAll` on browsers that support it (and I imagine most others will, too), and fall back to their own search functions on browsers that don't.

Comment: Would a recursive function be better than getting all `span` elements? I'd assume getting the `span`s should be faster.

Comment: @FelixKling: I wouldn't assume it was, an RD search of the DOM is really quite fast (a while back I did tests using the all-in-one-page HTML5 spec, as it's **massive**, and was very impressed even with older IE versions), but I also wouldn't assume it *wasn't*. :-) Which is why I mentioned `getElementsByTagName` (but of course, not all active browsers support that -- soon, yes, we will be free of the 1990s horror that continues to plague us, but we aren't...quite...there...yet unless you ignore large corporate and government installations, and east asia -- which many sites can, of course).

Comment: @FelixKling: Or am I misremembering? Does IE6 have `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: I see... I didn't think about the memory actually (which you also mention (though it should be a list of references only as the DOM exists (but maybe I just don't know enough about the actual implementation (or I like nested parens ;))))). Anyway, it's good to know that recursive DOM traversal is not that bad, I thought it was "less optimal". Always learning something new :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, IE6 has it. `getElementsByClassName` is the problematic one. quirksmode to the rescue: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t12

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks. Not the first time I've made that mistake. :-) Re the list: Yes, it's a list of things that already exist, but remember the overhead. `NodeList` instances are *live* (DOM modifications are automatically reflected in the list) so there's a *lot* of hooking up to do. But in a face off, I wouldn't be surprised to find some browsers favor one and others the other. I'd be surprised if there were a huge difference between them, either should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `document.getElementsByTagName()` to get a list of all spans. Then, check each span for the email attribute using `Element.hasAttribute`. Then you would use the Node interface to create and insert newe tags accordingly.

**EDIT:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', callback, true);

var callback = function() {
    var spanTags = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < spanTags.length; i += 1) {
        if (spanTags[i].hasAttribute('email')) {
            var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
            imgElement.setAttribute('src', 'yes.gif');
            spanTags[i].insertBefore(imgElement, spanTags[i].firstChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you unpack the answer a little bit more?

Comment: @smoldyr: You can *edit* your answer to flesh it out (and get the benefits of code formatting), using the tempting "edit" link underneath it...

Comment: It's easier for other readers to follow. Or do you think the code in your comment is easily readable?

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely misunderstood your point. I have no idea why I didn't think of that, still kinda knew here. I'm on it.

Comment: omg, just noticed the for-in loop being used as a for-each. -1 for bad practices...

Comment: `attachEvent` is an IE-ism, the standard is `addEventListener`. You still have to feature-detect to see which the browser supports (since even IE8 doesn't have `addEventListener` yet) and use the appropriate one (or use DOM0 -- `window.onload = callback;` -- but as you know there are very good reasons for not doing that). Also, I'm not sure how reliable it is cross-browser to index into the `NodeList` directly (rather than calling the standard `item` function). I'm not immediately finding anything about that in the spec, and it's awkward in some binding languages (the DOM isn't just for JS).